# SQL: Finding closest neighbor based on lat/lon

Tags: mysql, sql, latitude-longitude

I have a table containing the lat/lon of cafés. I would like to make an SQL query that gives me the closest café to each café. Can someone help with advice on how to do this?

The table basically looks like this:

Cafe ID

```
+-------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| cafe_id                 | gps_latitude         | gps_longitude        |
+-------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 011-1003                | 55.86649500000000000 |  8.16856200000000000 |
| 192-143                 | 57.04419159749860000 | 10.36447024359820000 |
| 037-0233                | 55.08773849210000000 |  8.56101036070000000 |
| 121-934                 | 56.89120900000000000 |  9.16818100000000000 |
+-------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If performance becomes a problem, add a "bounding box" to the `WHERE`.  If that is not good enough, see [_my blog_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/latitudelongitude-indexing/) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) to get the distance expressed in [earth-radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius).

Some prefer the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) because it gives better precision, but given that MySql's floating point precision is high enough, the difference between the two is negligible. The first one is simpler to implement:

```
select     c1.cafe_id,
           substring_index (
             group_concat( c2.cafe_id order by 
               acos(  sin(radians(c1.gps_latitude)) * sin(radians(c2.gps_latitude)) 
                    + cos(radians(c1.gps_latitude)) * cos(radians(c2.gps_latitude)) 
                      * cos(radians(c2.gps_longitude-c1.gps_longitude)) ) ),
             ',', 1) nearest
from       cafe c1
inner join cafe c2 on c1.cafe_id <> c2.cafe_id
group by   c1.cafe_id
```

Output for the sample data is:

```
|  cafe_id |  nearest |
|----------|----------|
| 011-1003 | 037-0233 |
| 037-0233 | 011-1003 |
| 121-934  | 192-143  |
| 192-143  | 121-934  |
```

Here is a [MySql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca9412/13).

#### Explanation

The distance calculation is used in the `order by` clause of the `group_concat` aggregation function, which results in a comma-separated list of *cafe_id* values in order of their distance to the cafe you group by. The `substring_index` function extracts the first item from that list.

The join condition is important as without it you'd get the cafe itself as the closest neighbor (its distance is obviously 0 then).

#### Set a limit to the distance

In comments you asked for a possibility to only include a neighbor in a certain radius.

In that case you could output the "distance", converted to km (miles would be a different factor):

```
select     c1.cafe_id,
           substring_index (
             group_concat( c2.cafe_id order by 
               acos(  sin(radians(c1.gps_latitude)) * sin(radians(c2.gps_latitude)) 
                    + cos(radians(c1.gps_latitude)) * cos(radians(c2.gps_latitude)) 
                      * cos(radians(c2.gps_longitude-c1.gps_longitude)) ) ),
             ',', 1) nearest,
           min(
               acos(  sin(radians(c1.gps_latitude)) * sin(radians(c2.gps_latitude)) 
                    + cos(radians(c1.gps_latitude)) * cos(radians(c2.gps_latitude)) 
                      * cos(radians(c2.gps_longitude-c1.gps_longitude)) ) )
             * 6371 km
from       cafe c1
inner join cafe c2 on c1.cafe_id <> c2.cafe_id
group by   c1.cafe_id
```

Now you can decide depending on the distance whether you want to ignore the neighbor. In case you really want to exclude the cafés whose closest neighbor is too far away, then add a `having` clause at the end:

```
having     km < 5
```

If you prefer miles, then use 3959 as multiplication factor in the SQL instead of 6371.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for including the explanation. Is there a way to only include the nearest neighbor within a certain radius?

Comment: You're welcome. For your additional question see the stuff I added to my answer.

Comment: @trincot Hi, I just read your answer for a similar question. If I need an additional column in the output table to show the distance between id and its closest neighbour (in meters ), how should i do it? Thanks!

Comment: The second query in the answer adds this column. It's in kilometers, but I suppose you know how to multiply by 1000 ;-)

Comment: @trincot I treid it in MySQL but it ran into an error :( 
 Can you please have a look? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca9412/62

Comment: Apparently, MySQL does not like the space between `min` and `(`. Remove it, and it should work. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for spotting the error!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
SELECT zip, primary_city, latitude, longitude,
      111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_km
 FROM zip
 JOIN (
     SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,  -70.81 AS longpoint
   ) AS p ON 1=1
 ORDER BY distance_in_km;
```

Can read more for this topic here :
http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Answer (score 1):

Bellow query helps to find out two(neighbour) nearest location.

Set variable in MySQL with current lat and lng value

```
SET @lat=55.866495, @lng=8.168562;
```

Execute query

```
(SELECT tbl.cafe_id , tbl.gps_latitude, tbl.gps_longitude, 111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@lat))
 * COS(RADIANS(gps_latitude))
 * COS(RADIANS(gps_longitude) - RADIANS(@lng))
 + SIN(RADIANS(@lat))
 * SIN(RADIANS(gps_latitude))))
 AS distance_in_km
FROM table_name as tbl ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC LIMIT 0,1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT tbl.cafe_id , tbl.gps_latitude, tbl.gps_longitude, 111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@lat))
 * COS(RADIANS(gps_latitude))
 * COS(RADIANS(gps_longitude) - RADIANS(@lng))
 + SIN(RADIANS(@lat))
 * SIN(RADIANS(gps_latitude))))
 AS distance_in_km
FROM table_name as tbl ORDER BY distance_in_km DESC LIMIT 0,1);
```

Comment: Hmmm... Seems like the first `SELECT` finds the "nearest", but the second finds the "farthest".